# How to create a simple gravity engine on javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to make a simple animation in javascript using P5.js library. I would like to make a ball appear at some height and then let it fall down and make it bounce until it comes to a stop.

I'm not looking for a external library, just P5.

My code is this:

```js
function Ball() {
    this.diameter = 50;
    this.v_speed = 5;
    this.ypos = height/2 - 100;
    this.xpos = width/2;

    this.update = function(){
        this.ypos = this.ypos + this.v_speed;
        this.ypos = constrain(this.ypos, this.diameter/2, height-this.diameter/2);
    }

    this.show = function(){
        ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.diameter);
        fill(255);
    }
}

var ball;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    ball = new Ball();
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    ball.update();
    ball.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can read the related [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_gravity.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to set the starting speed to 0 and define a gravity:

```js
this.v_speed = 0;
this.gravity = 0.2;
```

A working `update` method, which can be directly applied to your example, looks like this:

```js
this.starty = height/2 - 100;
this.endy = height-this.diameter/2;
```

```js
this.update = function(){

    this.v_speed  = this.v_speed + this.gravity; 
    this.ypos = this.ypos + this.v_speed;
    
    if (this.ypos >= this.endy){
    this.ypos = this.endy;
        this.v_speed *= -1.0; // change direction
        this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9; 
        if ( Math.abs(this.v_speed) < 0.5 ) {
            this.ypos = this.starty;
        }
    }
}
```

The key is to reduce the speed and to change the direction when the ball bounces on the ground:

```js
this.v_speed *= -1.0;
this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9;
```

See also [Bouncing Balls, struggling with getting more than 1 (processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454196/bouncing-balls-struggling-with-getting-more-than-1-processing/53456255#53456255).

See the example, where I applied the suggestions to your original code:

```js
function Ball() {
    
  this.diameter = 50;
      this.v_speed = 0;
      this.gravity = 0.2;
      this.starty = height/2 - 100;
      this.endy = height-this.diameter/2;
      this.ypos = this.starty;
      this.xpos = width/2;

      this.update = function(){

          this.v_speed  = this.v_speed + this.gravity; 
          this.ypos = this.ypos + this.v_speed;
          
          if (this.ypos >= this.endy){
            this.ypos = this.endy;
              this.v_speed *= -1.0; // change direction
              this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9; 
              if ( Math.abs(this.v_speed) < 0.5 ) {
                  this.ypos = this.starty;
              }
          }
      }

      this.show = function(){
          ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.diameter);
          fill(255);
      }
}

var ball;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    ball = new Ball();
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    ball.update();
    ball.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/example/p5.js/p5_js_so/p5js_so_bouncing_ball_1.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, here is a working(but crude) way of doing it:

```
var velY = 0;
var yPos = 0;
draw = function() {
velY += 0.1;//Make this value higher for stronger gravity.
yPos += velY;

if (yPos > 400) {
velY = -velY;
yPos = 400;
}//This may need a little tweaking.

ellipse(300, yPos, this.diameter);
};
```